# Camera rotation (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

I am having trouble with a camera class I am trying to use in my program. When I change the camera_target of the gluLookAt call, my whole terrain is rotating instead of just the camera rotating like it should.

Here is some code from my render method:

```
camera->Place();

    ofSetColor(255, 255, 255, 255);

 //draw axis lines
 //x-axis
 glBegin(GL_LINES);
 glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
 glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
 glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f,0.0f);
 glEnd();

 //y-axis
 glBegin(GL_LINES);
 glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
 glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
 glVertex3f(0.0f, 100.0f,0.0f);
 glEnd();

 //z-axis
 glBegin(GL_LINES);
 glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
 glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
 glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f,100.0f);
 glEnd();

 glColor3f(1,1,1);

 terrain->Draw();
```

And the rotate and place methods from my camera class:

```
void Camera::RotateCamera(float h, float v){
hRadians += h;
vRadians += v;

cam_target.y = cam_position.y+(float)(radius*sin(vRadians));
cam_target.x = cam_position.x+(float)(radius*cos(vRadians)*cos(hRadians));
cam_target.z = cam_position.z+(float)(radius*cos(vRadians)*sin(hRadians));

cam_up.x = cam_position.x-cam_target.x;
cam_up.y = ABS(cam_position.y+(float)(radius*sin(vRadians+PI/2))) ;
cam_up.z = cam_position.z-cam_target.z;
}

void Camera::Place() {
//position, camera target, up vector
gluLookAt(cam_position.x, cam_position.y, cam_position.z, cam_target.x, cam_target.y, cam_target.z, cam_up.x, cam_up.y, cam_up.z);
}
```

The problem is that the whole terrain is moving around the camera, whereas the camera should just be rotating.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

From your code it looks as though your camera is stationary (cam_position doesn't change) and you just change cam_target. This will have the effect of spinning your camera around on the spot. If the only thing in your scene is your terrain then it might appear as though the terrain is rotating around the camera. Are you trying to rotate the camera around the terrain? In that case your camera target should be the center of the terrain and you should be changing cam_position to move the camera.

Try initializing cam_target to the terrain position and then in the lines where you currently update cam_target swap cam_target and cam_position:

```
cam_position.y = cam_target.y+(float)(radius*sin(vRadians));
cam_position.x = cam_target.x+(float)(radius*cos(vRadians)*cos(hRadians));
cam_position.z = cam_target.z+(float)(radius*cos(vRadians)*sin(hRadians));
```

Comment: Yep, that looks like what he's doing wrong. Good eye!

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually setting the identity matrix at any point?

What other matrix ops are happening, and in what order?